Is heat a state function when we consider an isobaric process in a closed system?
Consider a hydrostatic thermodynamic system, ie a $PVT$-system.
We have internal energy differential
$$dU=TdS-PdV+\mu dN\tag{1a}$$
$$=dQ-PdV=\mu dN\tag{1b}$$
and enthalpy differential
$$dH=d(U+PV)\tag{2}$$
$$=TdS+\mu dN+VdP\tag{3}$$
If the system is closed and the system undergoes a state change under constant pressure then $dN=dP=0$ and
$$dU=dQ-PdV\tag{4}$$
$$dH=TdS=dQ\tag{5}$$
Now, $H=H(U,P,V)$ is a function of the state functions $U,P,$ and $V$ and thus is a state function.
I have two basic questions.

Should $dQ$ be written as an inexact differential in (1b) and/or (4)? After all, in general, change in heat is path dependent. What about in (5)? The latter question is related to the following one.

In the specific case considered (closed system, isobaric process), is $Q$ a state function?


I understand that heat is a "path function". It is defined as an integral. If we fix pressure in a closed system and consider only the states with this fixed pressure (and fixed amount of gas), then is heat considered a state function?

Does a path function become a state function if we eliminate all paths but one? In a way it does, in other way it does not.

What makes you think that P is constant in a closed system?

@ChetMiller Nothing, I don't think that.

I have absolutely no idea why this question was closed.

In equation (1) it is implicit that the path under consideration is reversible since the equality requires that $dQ=TdS$. A better way to identify when the heat behaves as a state function is to start with the more general $$dU = dQ+dW$$
from which follows
$$dH = d(U+pV) = dQ+dW + pdV + Vdp$$
and impose the constraint of constant pressure so that
$$dH = dQ+dW + pdV $$
At constant pressure and assuming only pressure-volume work, necessarily
$$dW=-pdV$$
so that
$$dH = dQ $$
You might state that in this particular instance dQ behaves as a state function, but it would be somewhat sloppy and it's better to keep with the general definitions of work and heat as path-dependent properties, as the value of the heat would not become independent of path, a defining property of state functions. The conditions of only pV work and constant p are rather tight constraints that eliminate all but one possible path. A label can be used to indicate that under these particular conditions the heat is generated reversibly and the second law can be invoked:
$$dQ=dQ_\mathrm{rev}=TdS $$

Nitpickers could say that the d operator should not be in italic and should not be used for heat nor work  :-)  But I do agree it is a tedious editing work to set it so.

@Poutnik Yes, $\unicode{273}$ or $\delta$ would be less ambiguous, I agree.
